# PHPUnit can't find test class if it is auto/manually loaded in bootstrap

Tags: php, phpunit, autoload

I've come across an unusual class loading problem in PHPUnit, initially experienced with 4.3.5 and now latest 4.4.2 as well (latest stable).

I have a bootstrap file which is loaded via a `phpunit.xml` automatically, which includes Composer's default autoloader and also my own autoloader. This works fine as it is. However, I discover that if I load a test class *in* the bootstrap, then PHPUnit isn't able to resolve the class name correctly, and it thus does not load.

I get this error:

> Class 'test/unit/tests/UpdateAllTest' could not be found in '/full/project/path/webapp/test/unit/tests/UpdateAllTest.php'.

(My purpose in wanting to refer to a test class in the bootstrap is to add a database build method in each one, keeping it with the test file it pertains to. I plan to do this in the bootstrap rather than a `setUp()` method, as I want it to run once across all tests, not once per test method).

I've done a bit of light debugging inside PHPUnit itself (in particular `PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader::load`) and found the class name is incorrectly supplied as a path and not as a namespaced class name. Here is the relevant clause:

```
    if (class_exists($suiteClassName, false)) {
        $class = new ReflectionClass($suiteClassName);

        if ($class->getFileName() == realpath($suiteClassFile)) {
            return $class;
        }
    }
```

The value of `$suiteClassName` is `test/unit/tests/UpdateAllTest`, which is plainly not a namespaced anything - it should be `Awooga\Testing\Unit\UpdateAllTest`, something that is normally handled by a custom mapping in my autoloader.

I don't think I am doing anything *particularly* unusual with PHPUnit, and so find it unlikely that this is a bug that no-one else has thus far experienced. In these circumstances, do I maybe need to declare the class namespaces in the `phpunit.xml` or something unusual like that? Grasping at straws here!

What might be the cause of this seemingly trivial problem? In the meantime I will just move these set-up methods to a different file/class - not ideal but not the end of the world either. I'm on PHP 5.5.x and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Is the class in your Bootstrap file namespaced?

Comment: @Schleis, thanks: the class is, yes, and it auto-loads fine there. It's only after this that PHPUnit fails to realise it is already loaded, and does not instantiate it.

Comment: I can't tell from your question but are you sure that you are referring to the class with the proper namespace when it isn't being found?

Comment: Yes, I am sure @Schleis. It is PHPUnit that doesn't find it, not PHP - if you look at the error, it has no line number, and it would do if it was a regular uncaught exception from PHP. The exception that raises this can be found in the source code of PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't fixed this, but my build methods are now so long that it makes sense for them to appear in different classes anyway. I have a naming convention so that a test of `*Test.php` has a corresponding build class of `*Build.php`.

I use PHPUnit's bootstrap system to scan for build classes and to call a static `build()` within automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are also experiencing [this problem](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1623).

Having the path as parameter is normal behavior at this point, check further down in `PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader::load` causes this confusing error message.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that does sound very similar. Do please let me know how you get on with that bug report. I searched the tracker also, and didn't find anything. I assumed that, since it seems to be such an obvious issue, that I must just be doing something wrong!

Comment: You're welcome. I will try to remember, but i don't think it will be fixed soon.